# Jackson json string -> object convert problem

Tags: java, jackson

I want to convert this string.

```
String str = "{ \"name\": \"\"shcheong\"\", \"age\": 27 }";
```

I expect to print name "shcheong" using jackson. but jackson can't convert and throw exception.

How can I convert to "shcheong".

======Edit======

add my code.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
TestDTO testDTO = mapper.readValue(str, TestDTO.class);
        
System.out.println(testDTO.getName());
System.out.println(testDTO.getAge());
```

And
TestDTO.class

```
public TestDTO {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    ----via Getter and Setter----
}
```

Comment: will you add - what's the exception you got

Comment: add how are you reading the json

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is about repeated quotes

```js
\"\"shcheong\"\"
```

If you want to put `"` as a part of the JSON attribute, you have to double escape the character.

```java
String str = "{ \"name\": \"\\\"shcheong\\\"\", \"age\": 27 }";
```

Or you can apply `String.format` to make code less verbose.

```java
String str = String.format("{ \"name\": \"%s\", \"age\": 27 }", "\\\"shcheong\\\"")
```

Comment: I already know that. I can't use \\\" only use \".

Comment: So, if you know the cause of the problem, then what's the deal? And why you can't use `\\\"`?

Comment: I receive message like that string from another server.

Comment: Well, this string is not a valid JSON. Therefore, it can't be parsed. There are several approaches depending on your case. You can just reject the request and log the error. Or you can try to normalize the string. For example, try to find duplicated quotes and replace them with regular expressions.

Comment: @SeokHyunCheong If you receive the message "from another server" and the message is illegal, you **can't** parse it. Why do you think that Jackson knows how to deal with syntactically illegal JSONs?

Comment: @fluffy Thanks for your opinion. I know this string is illegal. I just wonder there are any options i missed.